# Keyboard interrupt bash and python script running in parallel

Tags: python, bash

I have to execute two operations at the same time, one through a bash script and another through a python script. The simplest way to do it that I've found so far is to create a parent bash script to execute the two in parallel, such as this:

```
#!/bin/bash

bash process1.sh &
python3 process2.py &
```

I want to be able to interrupt the two processes at the same time using keyboard interrupt Ctrl+C. I tried adding

`trap 'kill %1; kill %2' SIGINT`

but the python script does not close as I'd like. In the python script there is a loop that should stop after the keyboard interrupt and perform some more operations after that, something like this

```
try:
    # do something

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # Keyboard interrupt (Ctrl + C) detected
    pass

# then do some final operations
```

but using `kill` does not propagate the keyboard interrupt to the python script, it just terminates the program as it is.

Is there a way to not kill the child python script, but to propagate the SIGINT to it?

Comment: You can say `kill -INT %2` but I don't know if python will receive that as a _keyboard_ interrupt.

Comment: A quick test convinces me that it does.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sh
trap 'kill -INT %1 %2' INT
```

Comment: Just tried it, it kills the bash script `%1` but do nothing to the python script `%2`. The python script does not terminate the loop with `except KeyboardInterrupt:`

Comment: Well, change it. `except KeyboardInterrupt: exit()`

Answer (score 0):

`kill %2` sends *SIGTERM* (the default signal) to the Python process, not SIGINT. You want `kill -INT` inside the trap code.